# Oracle: Insert default value 0 into timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to insert a default value of 0 into an oracle `timestamp(6)` column?

I have a column `CS_Date_Time` defined as `Timestamp(6) NOT NULL`. In certain cases it is not valid to insert any value to this column. So instead of changing the definition to allow `NULL` values and leaving this column as `NULL` in these cases, I was looking for any alternatives.

Comment: No. 0 is a number, not a timestamp. What business problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a column "CS_Date_Time" defined as  Timestamp(6) NOT NULL. In certain cases it is not valid to insert any value to this column , So instead of changing the definition to allow NULL Values and leaving this column as null in these cases, I was looking for any alternatives.

Comment: Something like Jan 1 1960 00:00:00? But, why not allow nulls? That seems like the standard solution.

Comment: Yes, I think the best solution would be to allow null values for this column. Thank you so much for your comments.

Comment: There is at least one use case when such column is used for RANGE PARTITION - not even an exotic case

Comment: If there is no value then the column should be NULL. Using a sentinel value is a Really Bad Idea, because every piece of software which accesses this table will need to know what the sentinel value is, what it means, and must handle it correctly in all cases. If the database column is set up as NOT NULL then it's modeled incorrectly and needs to be reexamined.

Comment: Using fictitious dates is also a bad ideas from an optimizer perspective.

Answer (score 0):

0 is a number, not a timestamp. You can use a date which is clearly outside your business rule, e.g 0000-01-01 00:00:00 or 1900-01-01 00:00:00 or 2999-12-31 23:59:59

Of course, it should be only **one** special value over entire application, these values are just examples.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
  END_TIME TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT TIMESTAMP '9999-12-31 23:59:59' NOT NULL,
...
);
```

Comment: @wennfried Domscheit: I am gun-shy (nervous, anxious) about using valid values to represent null values. While you may document the heck about something like this, it will cause problems down the road when someone tries to use the data and is unaware of the special meaning values. As a for-instance, pretend this is a birth date and you want to  find in which month most people were born. Without knowing the "NULL" value, your answer is likely to be January or December, depending upon which value you chose. And you will always be coding around this value, where NULLs are much simpler to hand.

Comment: @BrianLeach Of course, using NULL values is much simpler and clearly the preferred design. However, you may have circumstances where NULL values are not possible (e.g. RANGE partition). Certainly you have to handle such special value properly in your entire application which requires additional coding effort.